# Which use of possessive is correct "I'm grateful for my mother's love" or "I'm grateful for the love of my mother"?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe, possessive-adjectives

Which use of possessive is correct

- "I'm grateful for my mother's love"

or

- "I'm grateful for the love of my mother" ?

Or are they both correct, but carry different meaning? I would say *"my mother's love"* but I can't find a logical explanation for that. Can anyone help me? Possessive case always confuses me, because I don't understand the logic behind choosing *'s* or *of*.

Answer (score 1):

> "I'm grateful for my mother's love" or "I'm grateful for the love of
> my mother"?

They are both correct. There may be a slight difference of emphasis, depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

Using *of* has a sort of formal, poetic or stilted feel. It's not how most people would generally talk (in my experience anyway) so it carries a different tone to using the usual *'s* possessive. You'll often see it for very grand descriptions or names of things, where using *'s* would sound more humble or mundane.

But they're both correct and interchangeable, although *of* starts to sound a bit ridiculous when you move from high concepts to things like "the food of my cat is all over the floor" as though you're telling an epic story.